# How do I set a text view size in iOS to display large amounts of text

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to iOS Development. I recently started out on swift and learnt all the basics. This is my first app, so please bear with me if it is a dumb question.

I am trying to do the following.

Have a text input field, where a user can enter a persons name. We then display an image from our storage and a bio in a text view.
So, here's my problem sometimes, the bio text is quite large and is getting truncated. I tried the scrollable option in the attributes panel, but I do not want the image to stay there when I scroll down. I want the image to move up, similar to how it does in a webpage. Anyway I can achieve this or any resource you could point me to?
PS: I have tried using the scroll view, but I feel I am messing something up as it is not working as intended, and is truncating it.

[image]
[image]

The first picture is my main storyboard. The second one is the attribute panel for my text view.

Please let me know if you need any further details which I did not post here. I don't know what else to post.

Edit:

I am using Auto Layout.

[image: I am using Auto Layout.]

Edit 2:

This is my View Controller Layout.[image: View Controller Layout.]

Edit 3 :

I have tried using a label with 0 lines like Beowulf suggested. But this is what happened.[image][image]

Edit 4: Updated with the images of constraints and latest result.
[image]
[image]

Please note that the "Hero Text View" is just a label.

Comment: if you have a textview and you want more text in it, the text view will simply scroll the text when the txt is more than the scrollview frame. You don't have to scroll the image view too, you just need to scroll the text in the text view. IF you don't want to scroll the textview, then you need to use auto layout to increase the textview according to textview frame.

Comment: @Mr.T , I am using Auto Layout.

Comment: umm .. I think they BOTH have to be INSIDE another holder, Quicksilver!

Comment: @beyowulf, please check the edit. Also, is there a way I can get the updates without messing up the question.

Comment: I am able to scroll now, however, the right side margin doesn't seem to work as intended.

Comment: @quick, if I get a minute I'll make a demo scene showing the autolayout way to do it.  it's not that hard though!  BTW you accidentally made a capital in the "L" of my nickname :/  :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the container view for the text view. Mostly, what you need to do is set the height of the text view based on the content of the text view. Text views don't have an intrinsic size like labels or images. So you should create height constraint for the text view. Create an IBOutlet for it then set it programmatically. After you get the text for the text view say something like:

```
self.heroTextViewHeightConstraint.constant =  self.heroTextView.contentSize.height
```

This will make it so your text view won't scroll, and, if you setup your scroll view correctly, it will resize to accommodate to fit all of its content.

If you truly don't want the text view to scroll you could just use a UILabel with lines = 0 and word wrapping, and you could avoid having to set any constraints programmatically.

Comment: I updated the question with the results I got when using a label. Please check and respond. Also, the functions you specified doesn't seem to exist in the latest version?

Comment: Can you post the constraints you have on the label? You want to avoid setting the height explicitly. I didn't specify any functions. I was using heroTextViewHeightConstraint as an example of what you might call the IBOutlet of the height constraint for the UITextView you were using perviously.

Comment: I'm sorry. I assumed self.heroTextViewheightConstraint is a function. I am updating the question with my latest results and constraints.

Comment: To get the label to appear without need to scroll horizontally, probably the easiest fix is to set its width equal to the textfield's. But you should also click on the red arrow next to view controller scene to figure out what constraints have not been satiably set, if it doesn't go away after you set the width. Don't ignore red or yellow arrows that appear there, or it will cause things to show up differently at run time. I'm guessing you also need to set a bottom constraint for your scroll view.

Comment: The missing constraint is the bottom margin for the text label. If I put it in, the text is being truncated. So, I had to remove it.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion I made? What was the result? When you add UI to a scroll view, a good practice to place everything in a content view that can size dynamically that will set the the contentSize of the scroll view. You can try that if you haven't gotten an acceptable result yet. That is drag out a UIView, place all of your ui in it and set it up the way you would any other view, add that view as a subview of the scrollview and pin the uiview top, bottom, left, right.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest loading your text view with attributed text that include the image built-in. That way the image will scroll as part of the text scrolling with no effort from you.

Starting in iOS 7 NSAttributedString has a method that will let you load an RTF file or RTFD file (RTF file with embedded images). The method that creates the attributed string directly from a file URL has been deprecated in iOS 9, but the method `initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:` is still supported.

You could create an RTFD file on your Mac that has the text and the image in it. Then drag that file into your project, load the file from your bundle into an NSData object, then use  `initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:` to load the data into an attributed string object that you can install into your text view.

Comment: Is there a way to add the textfield to the document, because it would make sense for that to scroll too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: If you do what I'm suggesting then the contents of the rtfd document, including images, become the contents of the text view, and scroll as a unit.

Comment: Yes, it's a neat trick. If you look at the screenshot in Edit 2, you see he added the textfield to the scroll view as well, just wondering if he can add UITextField to an RTFD file.

Comment: @DuncanC, That might be fine for this very basic and particular case. But If I am to show other stuff like, say age and profession. I would have to create a completely new file with images embedded in it. I do not think thats the way to go.

Comment: In that case you will need to lay out your contents in a scroll view as you describe. Beyowulf's suggestion of using a label with lines=0 is probably the way to go. That way the label will size itself to it's contents and your constraints will cause the other contents of the scroll view's content view to shift to make room.

Comment: Duncan - I have to say that's really not the way to go.  It's absolutely trivial to just make a holder with the image then the text, and scroll the whole thing.  I'm sorry but I have to downvote this. I'm surprised you would make such a recommendatio - TBC did you mean it in a pedagogic manner, ie, it would be advisable to ALSO master the technique you explain??